# Is "firmly" natural in "escorted him firmly back to his seat"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

> The flight attendants led the drunk man back to his seat, but just a few minutes later he had left his seat again. After a longer argument with the man, the flight attendants **escorted him firmly** back to his seat where he stayed for the rest of the flight.

I would like to know if "firmly" seems natural here to mean that they escorted him back to his seat in a serious way but not necessarily being too physical and using too much force on him? Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I think that would fit perfectly. None other synonyms of _firm_ feels like they do not use brute force.

Comment: "Firmly" need not be physical at all, just a non-nonsense attitude.

Comment: Did you write the quoted test, user118784? If not ,what is the source? Please, in future, provide title and author for all quoted text, and a link if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer, "the flight attendants firmly escorted him back to his seat." "Escorted him firmly" does not sound natural to me.

Comment: I didn't have a problem with  the original, but I see your point. I think the given order parses as [escorted him][firmly back to his seat], which doesn't make much sense - except as [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage), in which use it is quite normal.

Answer (score 1):

I think the original "escorted him firmly" is quite natural. It is technically, as a comment by Colin Fine points out, an example of [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage). Most native speakers will neither know nor care about that technicality, and simply say that "firmly" modifies "escorted" here, if they analyze the sentence at all.

This could mean simply "in a firm manner" or it could mean "with a firm grip", that is, physically. Additional context would be needed to determine which is meant.

I likew the original better than  "the flight attendants firmly escorted him back to his seat."  suggested by Mark Hubbard. But either is quite natural and would be understood by any fluent speaker.